# Ubuntu 22.04.1 freezes and crashes after a whule

Tags: freeze, crash

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 on an Intel CPU with an amd GPU. Recently it has started randomly freezing and subsequently (after about 20 frozen seconds) restarting a few minutes after boot. This has not happened before, and happens on both Wayland and XOrg. I have tried editing etc/default/grub, it did not help. What should I do?

Comment: Please post the last few lines of `/var/log/Xorg*log` and `dmesg`

Answer (score -1):

Update: uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox and Thunderbird, of all things, seems to have fixed the issue, apparently one of those was loading on startup and freezing.